# ReactiveCocoa 3: Map signal to value (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, frp

I'm pretty new to ReactiveCocoa 3 and Swift and have the following code example. I'd like to map the signal returned from the `map` function to receive the `JSON` values in the `start` function at the end.

At the moment I'm passing through a `Signal<JSON, NSError>` which I `observe` inside the `start` function. Is there a better solution to this?

```
import Foundation
import ReactiveCocoa
import SwiftyJSON

class SearchViewModel {

    let results = MutableProperty<[MyModel]>([])
    let searchText = MutableProperty<String>("")

    init() {
        searchText.producer
            |> map { keyword -> Signal<JSON, NSError> in Api().get("search/\(keyword)") }
            |> start(
                next: { signal in
                    signal
                        |> observe(
                            next: { jsonArray in
                                let models = jsonArray.arrayValue.map(modelAdapter)

                                self.results.put(models)
                            }
                    )
                }
        )

    }

}
```

#### Update:

It turned out the problem was my understanding of ReactiveCocoa. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out my `Api.get()` function should return a `SignalProducer` instead of a `Signal`. With this adjustment I ended up with a solution like this:

```
let keywordToJson: SignalProducer<String, NSError>  -> SignalProducer<JSON, NSError> = flatMap(.Concat) { keyword in Api().get("search/\(keyword)" }

searchText.producer
    |> mapError { _ in NSError() }
    |> keywordToJson
    |> start(
        next: { jsonArray in
            let models = jsonArray.arrayValue.map(modelAdapter)

            self.results.put(models)
        }
)
```

Notes:
(1) At the moment it seems to be necessary that you have to give the compiler some hints about the type of the `flatMap` function.
(2) You also need to remap the error of your properties `producer` from `NoError` to `NSError`.